# Adding new column in dataframe based on group condition in another column

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, group

I have a dataframe with several columns. I want to add a new column with values from Id (Column Id) in the dataframe based on a condition, the top 10 values from percentage (column Percentage) for each group of Type (Column Type). The rest of values in the new column should be "Unknown". There is several hundred of each group.

`

```
Name Percentage Type Id
Volvo 22 Car CFRE
Honda 14 Bike LOKJ
...
BMW 3 Car HURK
```

`
The new dataframe should be like this:

`

```
Name Percentage Type Id Name
Volvo 22 Car CFRE CFRE
Honda 14 Bike LOKJ LOKJ
...
BMW 3 Car HURK Unknown
```

`

I have a dataframe that have "Unknown" in the Name column.

`

```
Name Percentage Type Id Name
Volvo 22 Car CFRE Unknown
Honda 14 Bike LOKJ Unknown
...
BMW 3 Car HURK Unknown
```

`
Then I tried to use group_by() and order_by. But I can only get it working when using slice which results in a dataframe that only have the top 10 Names from each group and not the "unknown".

`df %>% group_by(Type) %>% slice_max(order_by = Percentage, n = 10)`

I would be grateful if someone can help me out and point in the right direction.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Type) %>%
  mutate(Name = if_else(Percentage >= sort(Percentage, decreasing=TRUE)[10],
                        Id, "Unknown"))
```

However, this code will result in an error if any `Type`-category has less than 10 rows or less than 10 non-NA values in "Percentage". If that might happen, you could set all values of `Id` to NA for such groups:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Type) %>%
  mutate(Name = if_else(sum(!is.na(Percentage))>=10 & Percentage>=sort(Percentage, decreasing=TRUE)[10],
                        Id, "Unknown"))
```

Comment: It almost working, however will this only add the top 10 of all Type combined, and not 10 from each Type.

Comment: By grouping by "Type" you should only get the top 10 from each type.

Comment: It only takes top 1 from 10 different Type (i.e I only get 10 in total).